# Heroku: upload single unversioned file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bash, heroku

I have a Rails 4 application hosted by Heroku.

Seeing as I'm working on an open-source project, there are several unversioned files containing sensitive information listed in `.gitignore`. For example, I have a `.secret` file at the root of the app that contains the key with which cookies are encrypted. I created this file by running the `rake secret` command.

My problem is that I cannot send this file to my heroku app since it is not versioned, it is not included in the deployment. Furthermore, I am using Github and cannot risk having my key disclosed publicly in the commit history.

I have attempted to use the `heroku run` command to create the file (`heroku run 'rake secret > .secret'` to no avail). I have attempted to connect with the terminal using `heroku run bash` but as the filesystem is ephemeral, my changes are not preserved when I exit the terminal.

Do you have any idea how I could achieve having unversioned files on a Heroku application?

Comment: The standard practice is to set them as ENV vars on Heroku.  Is there some reason you have to keep this info in a physical file when deployed (it's not safe as a file)?

Comment: I am looking at the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), it seems indeed like a better practice in terms of security and overall compatibility of the application with Heroku. Thanks a lot for this information. Care to make an answer so we solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret data (keys, passwords, etc) should be stored as config vars on Heroku.  They are then accessed via the `ENV` hash in your code.

If you use something like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro), you can place these vars in an application.yml (don't commit the file)

application.yml:

```
SECRET_KEY: my_secret_key
```

Figaro then has a rake task to push these to heroku:

```
rake figaro:heroku
```

Or, you can manually set them:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key
```

Finally, access them in your app as:

```
ENV['SECRET_KEY']
```

Comment: Much better than storing sensitive data in files. Thank you!